# How to assign users to a group and sort them using firestore reference field type

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of employees that has data sent to it. Right now there is 4 employees but eventually there will be many more.

I want to add a grouping feature so that the user can sort the employees by their group. I am trying to find the best way to assign these employees groups and I found the reference field type in cloud firestore and thought I could use it to solve my problem. But I am stuck and not sure the most efficeient way to use it to link employees to a group.

This is my database. Right now I have the employees doc (ex. 2569) and inside that is a sub-collection with 2 documents in itself.

[image]

[image: 2]

So end goal is to assign employees groups and then be able to sort and display them separately. Right now  I have the group name assigned in articles/group -> groupName: "example".

(display them hopefully with ".Where( "groupName"  "=="  "example" ) somehow in code without hard-coding the group name. The group name will be created by the user so it could be anything)

Is what I am doing a good start? I know this question is a little odd but I am stuck and could really use some pointers on where to head next.

Comment: I see that your collection/document database structure is `company (C) /companyID (D) /employees (C) /employeeID (D) /articles (C) /group (D)`. Is there a way that you could embed this `groupName` in a field inside the employeeId document without creating the `articles` collection? Now as I understand, you have two articles inside `articles` collection: `group` and `notes`. Perhaps, [collection groups queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) can be useful for your use case.

Comment: I would like to do that actually. I am not against changing my structure. My problem is how do I display the users separated by group wit just one field in each users profile(empID). I think I need some way of knwoing all of the group names so I can loop through them somehow. Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) would allow you to query all *articles* regardless of which *employee* contained them:

```
db.collectionGroup('articles')
  .where('groupName', '==', 'X')
  .get()
```

This would match documents in any collection (i.e. employees) where the last part of the collection path is *articles*. If you would like to find the employees who belong to a certain *groupName*, you may want to find the [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) by retrieving the collection this *DocumentReference* belongs to.

Once you have the [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent) of the *CollectionReference*, you will get a reference to the containing *DocumentReference* of your subcollection.